# Not getting Specific field value using Get method even its exists in collection and also in collection getData magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-collection

This is my code:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
```

I am Not getting Specific field value using Get method even its exists in collection query and also in collection array of `getData()` magento 2.

```
+----------+------+
| qty| get_type   |
+----+------------+
| 12 |  simple    |
+----+------------+
| 62 |configurable|
+-----------------+
```

Note : It contains some JOIN's but i am not getting some fields in `$collection` `$data->getTypeId()` in `foreach`